# Edited code in node modules is not rendering in browser using Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I am using angular 7 for my project and using a couple of 3rd party libraries. I made few js code changes in the package directly, but I am getting the updated code in the browser.

How to check the updated code changes in the browser.

Thanks for Help.

Comment: try to build your project, using ng build.

Comment: You should not make changes in 3rd party libs because later you won't be able to upgrade it.

Comment: @vinod ng build is going to create create a dist folder. I wanted to test it in develop mode.

Comment: @SaimaHaji I knew that it's not a good practice, but I wanted to check it first, later I can send a request to the team with the issue I was facing along with the solution.

Comment: @Anji, yes surely it will create dist folder but in order to reflect the changes you have to build your project, further for any reason you don't want dist folder you can delete it anytime you want.